# Why doesn't General Monroe use other means to intimidate Georgia?

Tags: revolution

Why didn't Monroe use blimps or hot air balloons if he wanted to bomb Georgia? Was this technology forgotten or did Monroe not care?

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely possible to create blimps without the use of electricity. This is a sign of a lack of intelligence on Monroe's part, or, more accurately, a sign of the increadibly shoddy writing on the creators of *Revolution*'s part.

Often in the past I've played games of *Civilization 4* with the proviso that electricity is impossible, and airships are just plain fun to bomb people with. Monroe should have played more video games and watched less *Star Wars* before the nano-bots came.

Answer (score 0):

A large blimp that can carry a decent payload would be a fairly easy target while a smaller faster balloon would only be able to carry a small payload

theres the issue of propulsion Im not entirely certain but I think you would need either electric power for propellers or you would need a way to manually power them otherwise you'd just be able to move with the wind

there is also the issue with bomb guidance without computers theres no way to make sure the bomb goes where you want it to go

of course as with any question I answer about revolution I must add that theres so much wrong with that show its really better not to dwell (I still like it for some reason though)